# Solr 3.1 index directory not found using post.jar from Windows CMD - newbie install following tutorial and getting #400 MIssing Solr Core Name error

Tags: windows, solr, indexing

Help. For the past two days I've tried to get Solr to index the exampledocs.  I've learned a lot, but am completely stuck.  I've tried it on two different Windows 7 PCs.

I'm following the basic tutorial at http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html, I tried with Solr 1.4 and 3.1.  I can get to the Solr admin page just fine and everything seems to be working at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/.

Following the next step in tutorial to create sample index with java -jar post.jar *.xml  inside Windows CMD screen.   The process starts to read the first file (HD.xml) and then throws me the **#400_Missing_Solr_Core_Name_in_path** error.

I get same error when I try with **-Durl=http://localhost:8938/solr/update** command.

When I run start.jar, I can see in the resulting msgs:
*Warning [] Solr index directory 'solr.\data\index doesn't exist.  Creating new index.*

I can then see the new data\index subdirectory, but why isn't solr recognizing it when using the post.jar?
I have not changed anything in the solrconfig.xml, which shows: ${solr.data.dir:}

My Solr admin shows this: cwd=C:\Program Files\Solr3\example SolrHome=solr.\

My directory structure is simply:

```
Solr3\client
solr3\contrib
solr3\dist 
solr3\docs
solr3\example
solr3\example\etc  
solr3\example\example-DIH   
solr3\example\exampledocs   
solr3\example\lib
solr3\example\logs
solr3\example\multicore   
solr3\example\solr\bin
solr3\example\solr\conf   
solr3\example\solr\data   
solr3\example\solr\data\index

solr3\example\webapps   
solr3\example\work   
solr3\example\start.jar
```

I'm pulling my hair out just following the basic tutorial.  Granted I'm using Windows OS, but what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
FINALLY got it to work on a 3rd Win 7 machine.  Have no idea what went wrong on the first two... didn't think that the file structure of Solr would be so delicate.  I had installed Lucid on the first PC (successfully) to learn and then tried using Solr under Tomcat, (defaults to :8080 instead of standard :8983), which probably buggered things up.   Was surprised that I couldn't get basic Solr on Jetty to work on a 2nd clean Win7 PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you have a [multi-core setup](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin), but you forgot to include the core name in the URL. So either you're running the multicore example or you modified the original default example.

If I run these simple steps it all works fine (Windows 7 64-bit, Java 1.6.0_20)

- Unzip apache-solr-3.1.0.zip
- Go to the "examples" directory, run `java -jar start.jar`, this launches the Solr server.
- Go to the "examples/exampledocs" directory, run `java -jar post.jar *.xml`, you'll get this output:

  ```
  SimplePostTool: version 1.3
  SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file gb18030-example.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file hd.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file ipod_other.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file ipod_video.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file mem.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file monitor.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file monitor2.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file mp500.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file sd500.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file solr.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file utf8-example.xml
  SimplePostTool: POSTing file vidcard.xml
  SimplePostTool: COMMITting Solr index changes..
  ```

Comment: Hi Mauricio, thanks for the quick response.  I'll try it all over again on yet another machine, but I swear I'm following exactly what you did.  For some reason Solr just keeps thinking I've got a multicore setup no matter how many times I install/reinstall.  Is there anyway to explicitly tell it that I don't have a multi-core?  I tried using -Durl=http://localhost:8938/solr/update, but get same error.

Comment: BTW, thank you for all your work and postings about SolrNet -- that's what led me to tinkering with Solr instead of SQL Server's iFTS (which we used with .Net at my last company).

Comment: @user766447: why port 8938? the default is 8983.

Comment: @user766447: go to the admin page and run any query? what's the resulting URL?

Comment: @user766447: also, just in case, you don't need to modify any file or environment variable in order to run this example.

Comment: 8938 was a typo when I was writing up this question on SO.

Comment: Yeah, I got it to run just as you said on a 3rd Win7 machine.  Now I'm cleaning up all my Solr directories in the first two PCs and will try again.  Thanks again for your help, I thought maybe there was a step missing since Windows uses backslashes instead of forward slashes like all the examples and in the solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Any suggestions on dealing with Windows paths in solrconfig.xml?  How would you write out the relative path of the location of the index files?   Seemingly a stupid question, but it's the little things that aren't in the tutorials that mess you up...

Answer (score 0):

From the [solr mailing list](http://markmail.org/search/solr+list%3aorg.apache.lucene.solr-user) :

> . . .
>
> The best tutorial is built right in:
>        http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html
>
> And you'll get your questions answered
>   here when you run into any   issues.
>
> Erik (Hatcher, the ,man!)

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's the tutorial that I'm using and having troubles with.  Joined the mailing group, but didn't see any Q&A, so still hoping someone on SO has the answer.

Comment: I love S.O. too, but sometime going to the software's user email group is the best bet. Now that  Mauricio has given you a real good idea of what the problem is, why not post to solr mailing list. Arg, Accidentally gave you Lucene info, not Solr. Doah! sorry! Link now replaced. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am running Solr on Windows/Tomcat. The Solr index files are located here for me.

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\solr\data\index**

(I expected the data\index folder to be in the Solr Home directory, but it was not. Not sure why.)